# Merging 2 Columns from Different Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables.

```
1.Message - Sender_Number,SMS,DateTime.
2.Replies - Receiver_Number,SMS,DateTime.
```

I want to combine all the Columns and merge the 2 DateTime Columns into one Column and order by the time.

For example:

```
Messages Table:
123 | Hello there. | 2012-10-22 3:50
121 | HI I like U..| 2012-10-22 9:10

Replies Table:
123 | how are u... | 2012-10-22 5:50
121 | HI I like U2 | 2012-10-22 9:30

DESIRED OUTPUT (In 1 table):
123 | Hello there. | 2012-10-22 3:50 
123 | how are u... | 2012-10-22 5:50 
121 | HI I like U..| 2012-10-22 9:10 
121 | HI I like U2 | 2012-10-22 9:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM messages
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM replies
) x
ORDER BY col3
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d190/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need an [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

It would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Sender_Number,SMS,DateTime FROM Messages
UNION 
SELECT Receiver_Number,SMS,DateTime FROM Replies
)
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Also, I wouldn't call a column `DateTime` cause it's a data type in `MySQL`. It could cause problems